# Change default locale from database , is that possible?

Tags: symfony

I have added a new configuration in my backend website, so I can change the language of all website.  It's working perfectly, but what I want to do now is make it so that the website opens with the language set on database; but I'm already using JMSi18nRoutingBundle, where my default locale is set to 'fr' for example.

How can I tell to JMSi18nRoutingBundle config to change the default locale from database. Is that possible?

Comment: Do you want save translation in DB?

Comment: I want to load the variable default_locale of this config
jms_i18n_routing:
    default_locale:       %locale%
default_locale must be loaded from database, from my entity Configuration

http://snapplr.com/snap/hx39

Look at this picture, when i change the language to french, the web site must open with new language ?

Answer (score 1):

You can make a RequestListener that is going to set the locale depending on the user.

```
class RequestListener
{
    protected $securityContext;

    public function __construct(SecurityContextInterface $securityContext) // this is @service_container
    {
        $this->securityContext = $securityContext;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $kernel          = $event->getKernel();
        $request         = $event->getRequest();

        //user must be logged in
        if ($this->securityContext->getToken()) {

            $user   = $this->securityContext->getToken()->getUser();

            //setting the locale for the user (used for error messages)
            $request->setLocale($user->getLocale());
        }
    }
}
```

And then you can even redirect to another route if needed. I don't know how JMSi18nRoutingBundle works, and if you'll need to add a default parameter to the URL or not.

Comment: You shouldn't inject the entire container, but only required dependencies.